# How to implement category/subcategory in django when root categories have the same subcategories?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, categories

I have this model Item:

```
class Item(CustomBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Each item belongs to a particular category which may be a sub-category of another category. In short, categories will look like following:

```
Men
    accessories
    clothing
        tops
        jeans
    sportswear
Women
    accessories
    clothing
        skirt
        pyjamas
    sportswear
```

So, root categories(men, women) will have the same sub categories.

I have read many resources and tried the following:

**1st Attempt:**

Categories table

```
id | name        | parent_id
 1 | Men         |
 2 | Women       | 
 3 | accessories | 1
 4 | clothing    | 1
 5 | tops        | 4
```

***Problems with this approach:***

- I need accessories for both men and women. I will have to duplicate accessories here.
- Making a query to this table will be difficult later on, in my opinion

**2nd attempt:**

I tried to use django-taggit. It worked just fine as tags.

***Problem with this approach:***

- Tags are not categories. There is no category/subcategory, parent/child relationship with tags.

What is the best way to implement this category/subcategory relationship?

Comment: http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/

Answer (score 2):

Just don't make Man and Woman a category. Accessories, clothing and sportswear are root categories.

For man and woman is the attribute of a product (may be for both—unisex—so make the sex multi value choice).

Then hardcode Man and Woman (or even Child) in the templates—it isn't likely there will be more sexes soon—and show only the categories which contain products for that sex.

Comment: I think I will anyways get into trouble when sub-categories go deeper and deeper later on, won't I?

Comment: I don't understand why. Can you give an example?

Comment: Also, don't implement e-commerce from scratch -- use Saleor! http://getsaleor.com/

Comment: I am not sure :) sorry, I will try this and let you know a little later

Answer (score 1):

add a field

`parent = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: This is the first attempt I described above :(

Comment: Nope. You've described `ForeignKey` approach. With multiple parents you don't need to have duplicated category records.

Comment: This should work, but I think mens->clothes is a different category from womens->clothes in case of searching for a categorie. With the approach above you will find mans as well as womens clothes when searching for clothes.